# How to please the borrow checker when trying to reuse a Vec with a lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

A common pattern that happens to me in Rust goes something like this:

```rust
struct Foo { /*...*/ }
struct FooProcessor {
    foos: Vec<&'??? mut Foo>, // this lifetime is the issue, see explanation below
    // other data structures needed for processing Foos ....
}
impl FooProcessor {
    // just to make it clear, `self` may outlive `input` and it's `Foo`s
    pub fn process(&mut self, input: &mut [Foo]) {
        // some example operation that requires random access to a subset
        self.foos.extend(input.iter().filter(|f| f.some_property()));
        self.foos.sort(); 

        // work some more on the Foos...

        // remove all references to the processed Foos
        self.foos.clear();
    }
}
```

The problem is the lifetime of `FooProcessor::foos`, as highlighted by the questionmarks above. All references to `Foo`s are cleared at the end of `process()`, but of course the borrow checker doesn't know that.

`FooProcessor` is usually a large, long lived object (specifically, it may outlive some `Foo`s), and I don't want to reallocate the `Vec<&Foo>` every time `process()` is called (not even by using some `SmallVec` thing).

Is there a good way to solve this that does not require the use of unsafe code (lifetime transmutation / pointers) each time I have this pattern?
(If the solution involves using some crate, it's of course fine if that crate uses unsafe internally).

Comment: You could make this work with a wrapper around `Vec<*mut Foo>` that can convert lifetimes safely by enforcing the inner `Vec` is cleared each time the lifetime changes. Then you can store it with `'static` lifetime in `foos` probably behind an `Option`. This would limit the use of `unsafe` to the wrapper, meaning you wouldn't need to use `unsafe` in `FooProcessor` itself.

Comment: @cdhowie: I thought about doing that. The thing is, sometimes I need a `Vec<Foo<'a>>` instead (`'a` coming from the `Foo`s passed as `input`), and then this doesn't really work again. So I thought there might be a general solution / crate for these things and wanted to ask the community.

Comment: Hmm, well `Foo<'a>` and `Foo<'b>` have the same layout per UCG so you can transmute. I'm trying to come up with a safe wrapper around the transmute operation.

Comment: The problem I'm running into is expressing the operation generically since Rust doesn't have a higher-rank concept like C++'s template-templates.

Comment: @cdhowie: I would love if you (or anybody) could come up with something like you are describing. Just gonna leave this open and hope :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transmuting `Vec<T>` to `Vec<U>` is in general unsound.  However, we can use [`Vec::into_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_raw_parts) to decompose the vector into a data pointer, length, and capacity, transmute the data pointer, and then use [`Vec::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts) to recreate the vector with the new type, as long as we can satisfy the invariants of `Vec::from_raw_parts`.

Well, we could... but `Vec::into_raw_parts` is unstable.  However, it is implemented in terms of public `Vec` methods, so it's trivial to copy and paste the implementation:

```
fn vec_into_raw_parts<T>(v: Vec<T>) -> (*mut T, usize, usize) {
    let mut v = std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(v);
    (v.as_mut_ptr(), v.len(), v.capacity())
}
```

Ok, now let's walk down the list of `Vec::from_raw_parts`' invariants:

---

> `ptr` must have been allocated using the global allocator, such as via the `alloc::alloc` function.

We are getting the pointer from a `Vec` that uses the global allocator.

> `T` needs to have the same alignment as what `ptr` was allocated with. (`T` having a less strict alignment is not sufficient, the alignment really needs to be equal to satisfy the `dealloc` requirement that memory must be allocated and deallocated with the same layout.)

`Vec` will ensure the allocation is aligned for `T`, so we can just have our function assert that `T` and `U` have the same alignment.  As the types are known at compile time, the compiler will elide this check if it would pass.

> The size of `T` times the `capacity` (ie. the allocated size in bytes) needs to be the same size as the pointer was allocated with. (Because similar to alignment, `dealloc` must be called with the same layout `size`.)

We will also assert that the sizes of `T` and `U` are equal, which satisfies this invariant.

> `length` needs to be less than or equal to capacity.
>
> `capacity` needs to be the capacity that the pointer was allocated with.
>
> The allocated size in bytes must be no larger than isize::MAX. See the safety documentation of pointer::offset.

We will get the length, capacity, and pointer from an existing vector, which must satisfy these invariants unless we've already hit some UB somewhere.

> The first `length` values must be properly initialized values of type `T`.

We will clear the vector before decomposing it, so `length` will be zero, satisfying this invariant vacuously.

---

Now we can define a safe transmutation between `Vec` element types in these terms:

```
fn safe_vec_transmute<T, U>(mut v: Vec<T>) -> Vec<U> {
    assert_eq!(std::mem::size_of::<T>(), std::mem::size_of::<U>());
    assert_eq!(std::mem::align_of::<T>(), std::mem::align_of::<U>());

    v.clear();
    
    let (ptr, len, cap) = vec_into_raw_parts(v);

    // SAFETY:
    //
    // We assert T and U have the same size and alignment, and we clear the
    // vector first.  This satisfies several invariants of Vec:from_raw_parts.
    // The remaining invariants are satisfied because we get ptr, len, and cap
    // from an existing vector.
    unsafe { Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr as *mut U, len, cap) }
}
```

To make use of this, you would store `foos` as `Vec<&'static mut T>`.  In `process()` you could `std::mem::take(&mut self.foos)` to steal the allocation, leaving behind a zero-capacity vector, transmute the lifetime using `safe_vec_transmute`, do your work with the vector, transmute the lifetime back to `'static`, and store it back in `self.foos`.

It would look something like this (untested code):

```
let foos = safe_vec_transmute(std::mem::take(&mut self.foos));

foos.extend(...);
foos.sort();

// More work

self.foos = safe_vec_transmute(foos);
```

Note that `safe_vec_transmute` [compiles (with optimizations) to exactly the same instructions as a function that clears a vector and returns it](https://godbolt.org/z/YPvP1ae4q), so there is zero runtime overhead!

Comment: Putting the `clear` into the transmute function and then `take()`ing is a really clever way to express this in a sound way. I like it! Unless somebody comes up with a generic wrapper type (I believe this might be soundly possible using some `SafelyTransmutable` trait or dynamic assertions or something) I will accept this.

Comment: *"You can define a safe transmutation between Vec types when the arguments have the same layout"* - not quite in general, see: [How do I convert a Vec<T> to a Vec<U> without copying the vector?](/q/48308759) The layout of `Vec` itself can change, though unlikely in this case where only the lifetime parameter changes.

Comment: @kmdreko That's what I'm basing the soundness on, that the underlying type of the reference doesn't actually change, only its lifetime. Based on what I'm reading in UCG, a change only to a lifetime parameter does not change layout. I agree it kind of rides the line, but I don't see a better way. It would be nice if Rust allowed us to extract the allocation from a `Vec` and reuse it for another `Vec`, though that may be problematic w/rt alignment. I may revise my answer with a more complex but provably sound approach.

Comment: @kmdreko Shame `Vec::into_raw_parts()` is unstable. That would be a very convenient and unintrusive way to ensure soundness.

Comment: @kmdreko That function uses all public members, though, so it's easy to copy-paste to create something that works on stable. Thoughts on soundness of this approach? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=52487ad8741223a48b8acc3668136352

Comment: @cdhowie Yeah that should be fine. I was mostly responding to the specific phrasing (that just because elements have the same layout doesn't mean their `Vec`s can be transmuted). Which *technically* applies to lifetimes as well (since type-system-wise they are different types) but because of the way sub-typing works, I don't see how it would be a problem in this case. Though I always prefer to stay on the side of caution when `unsafe` starts being used. :)

Comment: @kmdreko Right. Either way I think the function will compile down to a no-op anyway, so I'll update my answer to use the safer approach.

Comment: @ChrisB Note I've updated my answer to account for kmdreko's feedback.

Comment: @kmdreko Updated my answer again, I think I've made a version that is general enough to handle any type (not just references) and also sound.

Comment: @ChrisB Updated again, I believe this update solves the issue of needing a copy of the function for lifetime-parameterized types, as it's now extremely general.

Comment: @cdhowie: This is beautiful, and exactly what I had imagined. Thanks for all the work you put into this! As a final touch, I added a `fn temp_vec(&mut Vec<T>, impl FnOnce(&mut Vec<U>))`
convenience wrapper, and am now very happy :).

Comment: *That's what I'm basing the soundness on, that the underlying type of the reference doesn't actually change, only its lifetime* - doesn't this mean that `safe_vec_transmute()` should be marked unsafe, with the contract that `T` and `U` differ only by lifetimes?

Comment: Also, you can hoist the checks to compile-time: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9e8cd241397d9dc54b55b89f1d740b2

Comment: @user4815162342 That comment was referencing an earlier version that explicitly accepted only `Vec<&'a T>` and produced `Vec<&'b T>` by transmuting the `Vec` directly. The version in my answer is safe for any `T` and `U` with the same size and alignment, because it don't directly transmute the `Vec`.

Comment: @cdhowie Oh right, that makes sense. In that case the function indeed seems safe. I'd might choose a name along the lines of `vec_repurpose()`, since it's _not_ actually transmuting the Vec (with its elements, as transmute normally implies), because you clear it first. And I'd definitely consider switching to compile-time checks, not for efficiency, but to fail at compile-time rather than panic at run-time in case of incorrect usage. With compile-time asserts, the function becomes infallible _and_ panic-free.